# What is the benefit of calling ioread functions when using memory mapped IO

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

To use memory mapped I/O, we need to first call request_mem_region.

```
struct resource *request_mem_region(
                unsigned long start,
                unsigned long len,
                char *name);
```

Then, as kernel is running in virtual address space, we need to map physical addresses to virtual address space by running ioremap function.

```
void *ioremap(unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size);
```

Then why can't we access the return value directly.

From Linux Device Drivers Book

> Once equipped with ioremap (and iounmap), a device driver can access any I/O memory address, whether or not it is directly mapped to virtual address space. Remember, though, that the addresses returned from ioremap should not be dereferenced directly; **instead, accessor functions provided by the kernel should be used.**

Can anyone explain the reason behind this or the advantage with accessor functions like `ioread32` or `iowrite8()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `ioread8` / `iowrite8` or whatever to *at least* cast to `volatile*` to make sure optimization still results in exactly 1 access (not 0 or more than 1).  In fact they do more than that, handling endianness (They also handle endianness, accessing device memory as little-endian.  Or `ioread32be` for big-endian) and some compile-time reordering memory-barrier semantics that Linux chooses to include in these functions. And even a runtime barrier after reads, because of DMA.  Use the `_rep` version to copy a chunk from device memory with only one barrier.

---

**In C, data races are UB (Undefined Behaviour)**.  This means the compiler is allowed to assume that memory accessed through a non-`volatile` pointer doesn't change between accesses.  And that `if (x) y = *ptr;` can be transformed into `tmp = *ptr;` `if (x) y = tmp;` i.e. compile-time speculative loads, if `*ptr` is known to not fault.  (Related: [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) re: why the Linux kernel need `volatile` for rolling its own atomics.)

MMIO registers may have side effects even for reading so you *must* stop the compiler from doing loads that aren't in the source, and must force it to do all the loads that *are* in the source exactly once.

Same deal for stores.  (Compilers aren't allowed to invent writes even to non-volatile objects, but they can remove dead stores.  e.g. `*ioreg = 1; *ioreg = 2;` would typically compile the same as `*ioreg = 2;`  The first store gets removed as "dead" because it's not considered to have a visible side effect.

C `volatile` semantics are ideal for MMIO, but Linux wraps more stuff around them than just volatile.

---

From a quick look after googling `ioread8` and poking around in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/iomap.c#L11 we see that Linux I/O addresses can encode IO address space (port I/O, aka PIO; `in` / `out` instructions on x86) vs. memory address space (normal load/store to special addresses).  And `ioread*` functions actually check that and dispatch accordingly.

> ```
>     /*
>      * Read/write from/to an (offsettable) iomem cookie. It might be a PIO
>      * access or a MMIO access, these functions don't care. The info is
>      * encoded in the hardware mapping set up by the mapping functions
>      * (or the cookie itself, depending on implementation and hw).
>      *
>      * The generic routines don't assume any hardware mappings, and just
>      * encode the PIO/MMIO as part of the cookie. They coldly assume that
>      * the MMIO IO mappings are not in the low address range.
>      *
>      * Architectures for which this is not true can't use this generic
>      * implementation and should do their own copy.
>      */
> ```

For example implementation, here's `ioread16`.  (IO_COND is a macro that checks the address against a predefined constant: low addresses are PIO addresses).

> ```
>     unsigned int ioread16(void __iomem *addr)
>     {
>       IO_COND(addr, return inw(port), return readw(addr));
>       return 0xffff;
>     }
> ```

---

#### What would break if you just cast the `ioremap` result to `volatile uint32_t*`?

e.g. if you used `READ_ONCE` / `WRITE_ONCE` which just cast to `volatile unsigned char*` or whatever, and are used for atomic access to shared variables.  (In Linux's hand-rolled volatile + inline asm implementation of atomics which it uses instead of C11 `_Atomic`).

That might actually work on some little-endian ISAs like x86 if compile-time reordering wasn't a problem, but others need more barriers.  If you look at the [definition of `readl`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.1/source/include/asm-generic/io.h#L173) (which `ioread32` uses for MMIO, as opposed to `inl` for PIO), it uses barriers around a dereference of a `volatile` pointer.

(This and the macros this uses are defined in the same `io.h` as this, or you can navigate using the LXR links: every identifier is a hyperlink.)

```
static inline u32 readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr) {
    u32 val;
    __io_br();
    val = __le32_to_cpu(__raw_readl(addr));
    __io_ar(val);
    return val;
}
```

The generic `__raw_readl` is just the volatile dereference; some ISAs may provide their own.

[`__io_ar()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/io.h#L24) uses `rmb()` or `barrier()` After Read.  `/* prevent prefetching of coherent DMA data ahead of a dma-complete */`.  The Before Read barrier is just `barrier()` - blocking compile-time reordering without asm instructions.

---

---

**Old answer to the wrong question**: the text below answers why you need to call `ioremap`.

---

Because it's a physical address and kernel memory isn't identity-mapped (virt = phys) to physical addresses.

And returning a virtual address isn't an option: not all systems have enough virtual address space to even direct-map all of physical address space as a contiguous range of virtual addresses.  (But when there is enough space, Linux does do this, e.g. x86-64 Linux's virtual address-space layout is documented in [x86_64/mm.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt)

Notably 32-bit x86 kernels on systems with more than 1 or 2GB of RAM (depending on how the kernel is configured: 2:2 or 1:3 kernel:user split of virtual address space).  With PAE for 36-bit physical address space, a 32-bit x86 kernel can use much *more* physical memory than it can map at once.  (This is pretty horrible and makes life difficult for a kernel: some random blog reposed Linus Torvald's comments about how [PAE really really sucks](https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/).)

---

Other ISAs may have this too, and IDK what Alpha does about IO memory when byte accesses are needed; maybe the region of physical address space that maps word loads/stores to byte loads/stores is handled earlier so you request the right physical address.  (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Alpha-HOWTO-8.html)

But 32-bit x86 PAE is obviously an ISA that Linux cares a lot about, even quite early in the history of Linux.

Comment: ioremap returns virtual addresses right, my question is why can't we directly use the address and dereference it

Comment: @md.jamal: oh, I misread the question, sorry.  My answer is explaining why you need `ioremap` >.<.  You need `READ_ONCE` or `WRITE_ONCE` to cast to `volatile*` to make sure optimization still results in exactly 1 access (not 0 or more than 1).

Comment: What do you mean by more than 1

Comment: @md.jamal: updated my answer.  You could get multiple asm loads out of `tmp = *ioreg;` if `tmp` is used multiple times and the compiler decides to just reload from `*ioreg` instead of keeping `tmp` around in a register or stack space.  But not if the access is `volatile`.

Comment: @md.jamal: I think I was confused by the title.  Did you make up the name "ioread functions"?  I think I mistook that for `ioremap` that appears as the only similar-named function in your question.  You did mean READ_ONCE and WRITE_ONCE, right?

Comment: @md.jamal: ok, hmm, maybe they do something special on some ISAs.  WRITE/READ_ONCE are used for atomic variables in normal memory (cacheable).  I was guessing they might also be for IO memory but perhaps not.

Comment: @md.jamal: updated again: I was curious what ioread8 actually did.

Comment: So, why I can't simple define the pointer to the register as volatile and read it as normal memory variable?

Comment: @0andriy: You mean cast the result of ioremap yourself to `volatile uint32_t*` or whatever, if you know it's MMIO not `inl` IO space?  updated my answer again.  I was hoping people who wanted to know more would just read the linked source; LXR lets you click on function names to get to the definition.  And most of the functions are defined in that one `io.h` file.