# what is difference between readl() and *

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, memory-mapped-io

In linux kernel.
I get a reg [phy_addr], and do ioremap(), get [vir_addr],
when i want to get val of this reg, What's the difference between readl() and *?

```c
u32 value;

phys_addr_t phy_addr = 0x12345678; // it is reg addr

void *vir_addr = ioremap(phy_addr, sizeof(u32));

val = readl(vir_addr);
val = *(u32 *)vir_addr;
```

Comment: Goal of **readl()** (and friends) is to ensure that access to a memory-mapped register is properly treated as an I/O operation rather than just a basic RAM access. Study http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-1.shtml

Comment: One difference is that `readw()/readl()/writew()/writel()` and friends assume the hardware registers being accessed use little-endian byte order, and the functions convert the values to/from the CPU's native byte order.

Comment: @IanAbbott, not only, the `readl()` might take care about alignment, while `*` is violating that on some architectures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the benefit of calling ioread functions when using memory mapped IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113831/what-is-the-benefit-of-calling-ioread-functions-when-using-memory-mapped-io)